# WinForms controls out of size on bigger screens

Tags: c#, winforms

Back with a new problem, I've finished developing some program but when the client runs it on his computer he gets a white backround even when the forms backround color is set to black and all controls backrounds are also black. The second problem is that although I'm using Dock and Anchor, my form controls are still not resizing to to fit his bigger 18 and 15" monitors, I am developing on a small 10" netbook. And yet another problem is the size of buttons, big on my screen is tiny on his.. if only I could use % like in CSS

I have no code to show, this is all based on the properties I've set in the properties panels.

Comment: Did you make AutoResize as False ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this to fix

```
" Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms "
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx